# youtube-dl record live stream segmentation

Tags: streaming, youtube-dl

Would you please help me to record live stream as some segments with Youtube-dl?

For example record a live stream every 30mins automatically

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to record chunks of 30 minutes? What have you already tried?

Comment: yeah 
there is a live stream and I need record it as some segments  automatically.

make some parts of stream automatically(every 30 or 60 mins)

Comment: And what have you tried yet?

Comment: Almost nothing, I've searched about that but found nothing. even in it's documentation there is nothing about time zone or segmentation...

Comment: I'm not sure how time zones come into play here. Could you not write a script that starts youtube-dl, stops it after 30 minutes, then starts it again? Or does the output have to be perfectly contiguous? Does it all have to happen "live", or can you wait with the segmentation until the live stream is finished? Finally, what are you *actually* trying to achieve, i.e., why do you need 30 minute segments?

Comment: No
I've not tried to wright scripts.
It was an example I meant there is a 24 hours live stream(like BBC) and I want to record it in some specific parts or I want to make an archive.

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to capture live webstreams with youtube-dl using this command:

```
youtube-dl -f best "stream url" -o "path to output file"
```

Comment: So to capture the NASA stream which is live 24/7, use this:                      youtube-dl -f best "https://youtu.be/21X5lGlDOfg" -o "C:\aaa_youtube-dl\NASA.mkv"   !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`streamlink`](https://github.com/streamlink/streamlink) to download a live stream to a file on your local machine:

```
streamlink -o output.mp4 <url> best
```

Here, `<url>` can be a YouTube live stream URL.

You could wrap this call in a script that is periodically started (e.g. via `cron`)